# var from controller to view via app.js

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm actually learning node.js with expressjs, I have some project with structure:

*controllers/Home.js*
and
*views/index.ejs*

In my root directory I have app.js with code:

```
    app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
        Home.index();
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Home'
        });
    });
```

...but I want to send title from my controller file (Home.js) and function **index**, can you explain me how to do this?

Best regards.

Comment: your requirement is not clear. explain bit more clearly

Comment: @Darshan, I want to render my view (*.ejs file) from the controller Home.js (controller/Home.js).

Comment: pass the res (response) object into Home.index function like this Home.index(res) and call render from there.

Comment: you can use `exports.title` in home.js and require and access in app.js

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon can you explain me it with details? What should I add to Home.js and what should I add to app.js to read this var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

expose title from home.js file and access it in app.js as:

```
var home = require('home_path');

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: home.title
        });
    });
```

Option 2:

create additional some_file.js that gets `title` and passes to `some_handler_function` as:

```
var some_file = require('path_to_some_file');

app.all('/', some_handler_function);
```

**Node-Cheat Available:**

For complete code, get working node-cheat at [ejs_variable_access](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/stackoverflow_answers/ejs_variable_access) run `node server` followed by `npm install`.

Comment: Thanks, but how in my Home.js file export title var? Or maybe can I render the view in my controller? In this option I will make only Home.index() in "app.all".

Comment: I have created node-cheat for you access it [Github ejs_variable_access](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/stackoverflow_answers/ejs_variable_access)

Comment: Thanks for it, now it is working for me. I have second question to you, Before I was creating apps in PHP (MVC), the structure of MVC is stil using in Node.js or should I make it different? Regards!

Comment: great, please mark answer correct and  repo. Yes MVC is good fit depending on nature of project, It keeps things clear and separated.